# Fill Ionic Slide Box

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I am new in programming apps with ionic and have question.
How can I dynamic fill a slide box in ionic?

I got met items from a REST Server which I want to add to my slide box.

Thanks for helping.

my data

```
$.get("https://ssl3.world4you.com/ithartl/tracktor/rest/traktors/1",function(responseText){
        var obj=responseText;
        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
         alert(obj[i].Description);
    }


<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="box fahrzeug"><h3>Fahrzeug</h3></div>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="box ford"><h3>Ford</h3></div>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <div class="box fendt"><h3>Fendt</h3></div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <div class="box steyrer"><h3>Steyrer</h3></div>
          </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: have you created any web method for that?

Comment: yes, i already created a get with jquery. i already gotmy data but i want to fill the slide box

Comment: can you please add some code ?

Comment: code is added now

Comment: create new method for read all record for Slide box..current API give only 1 record details...

Comment: does exist any example for that?